# strings and a store

Tags: c++, pointers, set, element, stdvector

In the below program a string is added to an empty store. Then the address of this store element is stored in the pointer 's1'. Then another string is added and this somehow causes the pointer to the original element to fail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class store2
{
    public:
        void add(std::string s) {words.push_back(s); last_added2 = &words.at(words.size() - 1);}
        std::string* last_added() {return last_added2;}

    private:
        std::string* last_added2;
        std::vector<std::string> words;
};

void main()
{
    store2 store;
    store.add("one");
    std::string* s1 = store.last_added();
    std::cout<<*s1<<std::endl;
    store.add("two");
    std::cout<<*s1<<std::endl; // crash
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a new item to an `std::vector`, the vector might require to expand its buffer, and by doing this it will probably move the buffer in a different memory area. Thus pointers to its element become invalid. To make it short, pointers to the items of a vector are not guaranteed to be valid after resizing a vector, and `push_back` may resize the vector if it hasn't got enough reserved space.

You could reserve space for the vector at the beginning, but then you'll have a limit to the number of items you can allocate into your vector.

Comment: It dosn't need to be a std::vector and many of the std::vectors abilities are not required but it does need to resize and elements do need to be reliably addressable.

Comment: If you don't need random access you could use a `std::list`

Comment: Is is possible to access the most recently added item to a list and keep addresses to individual elements?

Comment: Yes, lists allow you to access first and last element in `O(1)`.

Comment: Fantastic. I can't see any problems. I'm using std::list<std::string> words; and {words.push_back(v); last_added2 = &words.back();}

Answer (score 1):

If you need to assure that pointers into the collection remain valid, you probably want something other than a vector (e.g., you could use a `std::deque` or `std::list` instead -- with `std::deque` generally being preferred between the two).

Alternatively, instead of returning a pointer (generally a poor idea anyway), you could return the index of the string, and provide a member function that indexes into the vector when it's used.

Comment: It's a good idea with the index number, but wont work for the larger problem of which this is a simplification. I'm using your and peoro's std::list solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any particular reason you want to use pointers(heap)?
If not, just do:

```
   class store2
    {
        public:
            void add(std::string s) {words.push_back(s);}
            std::string last_added() { if (words.size() == 0) return "";
return words[words.size()-1];}

        private:
            std::vector<std::string> words;
    }
```

;

Comment: +1 for the obvious way without saving temporaries that might get invalidated (alternately use `words.back()` ).

Comment: I need to return pointers to the elements not copies of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector`'s iterators can be invalidated when its content is modified. See [vector iterator invalidation](http://learningcppisfun.blogspot.com/2007/01/vector-iterator-invalidation.html).

If you really want to keep the existing interface and retain pointers from elements inserted to your vector, you can store string by pointers and not by value, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class store2
{
public:
    store2 ()
    {
    }

    ~store2 ()
    {
        for (std::vector<std::string *>::iterator it =
                 words.begin (), end_it = words.end ();
             it != end_it; ++it)
        {
            delete *it;
        }
        words.clear ();
    }

    void add (const std::string & s)
    {
        std::auto_ptr<std::string> v (new std::string (s));
        words.push_back (v.get ());
        v.release ();
    }

    std::string *last_added ()
    {
        return words.back ();
    }

    const std::string *last_added () const
    {
        return words.back ();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string *> words;
};

int main ()
{
    store2 store;
    store.add("one");
    std::string* s1 = store.last_added();
    std::cout<<*s1<<std::endl;
    store.add("two");
    std::cout<<*s1<<std::endl; // no crash :-)
}
```

There is also [`ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) class in Boost that aims to make this kind of solution more reusable and robust (i.e. automatically manages memory, so you don't have to worry about deleting string when erasing its pointer from vector etc).

Comment: Thanks. But I will go with peoro's solution involving lists. This is a verry complex way of doing it. It's a good answer if it works though as it preserves both the use of vectors and the interfaces of store.